# Unreal GAS: When a GameplayAbility is considered as executed

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

In Unreal GameplayAbilitySystem, e.g. *Cancel Abilities With Tag* [is documented](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/GameplayAbilitySystem/GameplayAbility) with

> Cancels any **already-executing** Ability [..]

and the source code says (in GameplayAbility.h)

> Abilities with these tags are cancelled **when this ability is executed**

To know at design time, which abilities will be affected when setting those tags, it is required to be sure about:

**When a GameplayAbility is considered as executed and when as executing?**

---

According to the documentation linked above, the GA is executed with `CallActivateAbility()`. However, activation can be interrupted, if cooldown/costs conditions are not fulfilled (e.g. "not enough mana") in `CommitAbility()`.

`CommitAbility()` checks if the ability can be activated via `CommitCheck()` (cooldown/costs) and only if this succeeds, `CommitExecute()` is called (which applies cooldown and costs).

Before `CommitAbility()`, `PreActivate()` is called, which

1) sets (for instanced GameplayAbilities):

```
// ...
bIsActive = true;
bIsBlockingOtherAbilities = true;
bIsCancelable = true;
// ...
```

2) and blocks/cancels other GameplayAbilities with given tags using `UAbilitySystemComponent::ApplyAbilityBlockAndCancelTags`

---

Detailed questions which might help to answer the question above:

1. Is **executing** a GameplayAbility the same like **activating** a GameplayAbility or have these terms different meanings? (both terms are used in documentation and function names/variables)
2. Is a GameplayAbility always considered as executing as soon as `PreActivate()` is called? (since that function blocks/cancels other abilities via `ApplyAbilityBlockAndCancelTags` and therefore - according to the second quote above - is considered as executing)

   This would imply, that a GameplayAbility is considered as executing

   - independently from the outcome of `CommitAbility()`?
   - **as long as `UGameplayAbility::ActivateAbility()` is executing?**
3. How is a GameplayAbility detected as executing?

   - Is it enough to check for `UGameplayAbility::bIsActive == true` (for instanced GameplayAbilities)?
   - Or are executing abilities registered somewhere in `UGameplayAbilitySystem`?
   - ...

Answer (score 4):

## Hypothesis

The terms *activate*/*execute* a GameplayAbility (GA) and *active/executing GameplayAbility* are used when the abilities influence each other with [GameplayTags](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/Tags). So when designing, these terms are important for understanding the **GameplayAbility interaction via tags**. As a consequence, an:

1. activated/executed GA may block/cancel other GAs (via adding tags)
2. deactivated GA may unblock other GAs (via removing tags)
3. active/executing GA must be able to receive a block/cancel via tag changes, when another GA is executed

## Conclusion

To make best usage of tags for controlling the interaction between GameplayAbilities, keep the following in mind: A GameplayAbility is

- **activated**/**executed** when `CallActivateAbility()` is called (in blueprint, the `Event ActivateAbility` and `Event ActivateAbilityFromEvent` are triggered by that function via `ActivateAbility()`).
- **deactivated** when `EndAbility()` is called (which is also called by `CancelAbility()`).
- **active**/**executing** between the calls of `UAbilitySystemComponent::TryActivateAbility()` until `EndAbility()`.

  In case that `EndAbility()` is not called, the GA is executing for the lifetime of `ActivateAbility()` (again, in blueprints this is almost similar to the lifetime of the implemented `Event ActivateAbility` and `Event ActivateAbilityFromEvent`).

## Explanation

### When a GA is considered activated/executed and deactivated (1, 2)

`UAbilitySystemComponent::ApplyAbilityBlockAndCancelTags()` triggers GAs to be cancelled or blocked/unblocked. Therefore calls to it define the moment of activate/execute and deactivate.

- Block/cancel are called by `PreActivate()` which is called by **`CallActivateAbility()`**
- Unblock is called by **`EndAbility()`** (which is also called by `CancelAbility()`)

### When a GA is considered active/executing (3)

#### When it can be blocked

A GA can be blocked only during its activation. `CanActivateAbility()` checks (via `DoesAbilitySatisfyTagRequirements()`) the blocked tag list of the GameplayAbilitySystemComponent (ASC) (`UAbilitySystemComponent::BlockedAbilityTags`). If one of the tags is present there, the ability activation is aborted.

#### and when it can be cancelled (unregarded the fact if the GA allows it)

A GA can be cancelled by other GAs via tags as long as it is registered in the GameplayAbilitySystemComponent (ASC) in `UAbilitySystemComponent::ActivatableAbilities` and as long as that stored *GA spec* returns `FGameplayAbilitySpec::IsActive() = true`.

- It gets added to that container via `UAbilitySystemComponent::GiveAbility()` and removed via `UAbilitySystemComponent::ClearAbility()`
- `FGameplayAbilitySpec::IsActive()` will return true, as long as `FGameplayAbilitySpec::ActiveCount > 0`. This variable will be incremented upon GA activation (in `UAbilitySystemComponent::InternalTryActivateAbility()`) and decremented upon GA deactivation (in `UAbilitySystemComponent::NotifyAbilityEnded`).

`UASC::InternalTryActivateAbility()` is called in `UASC::TryActivateAbility()` and `UASC::NotifyAbilityEnded()` is called in `EndAbility()`. These two conditions are the reason that I considered a GA only as active/executing between those calls instead of between `UASC::GiveAbility()` and `UASC::ClearAbility()`.

#### How those tags are triggered

When a GA is activated/deactivated, it triggers functions in the GameplayAbilitySystemComponent (ASC):

For un-/blocking

1. `UAbilitySystemComponent::ApplyAbilityBlockAndCancelTags` calls ...
2. `UAbilitySystemComponent::BlockAbilitiesWithTags()` respectively `UAbilitySystemComponent::UnBlockAbilitiesWithTags()`, which (finally) call for each of the tags in its list `UAbilitySystemComponent::BlockedAbilityTags` ...
3. `FGameplayTagCountContainer::UpdateTagMap_Internal()`, which adds respectively removes the tag

For cancelling

- `UAbilitySystemComponent::CancelAbilities()` which compares the tags provided by the cancelling GA with the tags of all activateable abilities stored in the Ability System Component (in `UAbilitySystemComponent::ActivatableAbilities()`), which are currently active.
- If there is a match, all of those GA instances are cancelled.

### What about `CommitExecute()`

That function is independent from interacting with other GAs via tags, so the *Execute* part of the name can be misleading.

`CommitExecute()` is called only if the costs of the GA can be afforded and if the GA is not on cooldown (all of that happens in `CommitAbility()`). But blocking/cancelling other GAs already happened before and unblocking GAs also happens independently from that function.

### So what about `CommitAbility()`

For an *executing GA*, it doesn't matter, if this is being called.

If `CommitAbility()` fails, the GA might be deactivated immediately after being activated, *depending on the implementation of the GA*. So it can have an influence on the execution duration, which however is unimportant for the design process of the GAs interaction via tags.

### What about `SetShouldBlockOtherAbilities()`

This public function can be called to un-/block other GAs via tags from an arbitrary place in C++/blueprints.

E.g. it could be called several times during the lifetime of `ActivateAbility()` to un-/block other GAs. Furthermore, it is not able to cancel other GAs. It is not clear what are the best practices for using or avoiding this function. It seems to lower the transparency of GA interaction via tags.

---

(if no parent namespace is present, all functions are members of `UGameplayAbility`)

Other ways to block/unblock GAs (e.g. via inputID) or cancelling GAs (e.g. via `UAbilitySystemComponent::CancelAllAbilities()`) are not considered. This is about GA interaction via tags. Also triggering GAs via tags (or GameplayEvents) is another topic.

It would be nice if a designer of the Unreal GAS could clarify things, correct incomplete conclusions or leave some words about best practices.